# Formulario Dinamico : Criar e remover inputs

Tags: php, input, dinâmico

Estou tentanto desenvolver um formulário que crie e remove os inputs de acordo com a escolha do usuario.

Consegui fazer com que seja criado apenas um tipo de input por vez por meio do javascript, mas o projeto tem 9 input a cada linha gerada. Ou seja, cada vez que o usuario clicar, ele deve gerar 9 inputs diferente e depois armazenar tds os inputs no Banco de Dados.

Estou sem saber qual o jeito mais viavel de fazer isso. Se seria o caso de aprender uma nova linguagem de programação, gostaria de saber qual é a melhor p fazer esse comando.

Agradeço qq ajuda
Já olhei e n to cn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma das formas de fazer isso seria, como você mesma citou, usar o javascript para criar o formulário. Para salvar, você pode usar o PHP, para isso, na hora de criar o formulário, seria criado um array de campos. Ao postar o formulário, o PHP faria o loop neste array e gravaria um registro para cada linha do formulário.

Aqui tem um exemplo simples, utilizando JQuery que adiciona uma linha com 3 campos. O link com o passo a passo você pode ver neste endereço. http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/create-dynamic-form-using-php-jquery-and-mysql.php

Abaixo segue o formulário:

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="form_style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function add_row()
{
 $rowno=$("#employee_table tr").length;
 $rowno=$rowno+1;
 $("#employee_table tr:last").after("<tr id='row"+$rowno+"'><td><input type='text' name='name[]' placeholder='Enter Name'></td><td><input type='text' name='age[]' placeholder='Enter Age'></td><td><input type='text' name='job[]' placeholder='Enter Job'></td><td><input type='button' value='DELETE' onclick=delete_row('row"+$rowno+"')></td></tr>");
}
function delete_row(rowno)
{
 $('#'+rowno).remove();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="form_div">
 <form method="post" action="store_detail.php">
  <table id="employee_table" align=center>
   <tr id="row1">
    <td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter Name"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="age[]" placeholder="Enter Age"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="job[]" placeholder="Enter Job"></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" onclick="add_row();" value="ADD ROW">
  <input type="submit" name="submit_row" value="SUBMIT">
 </form>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

E aqui a página PHP que vai gravar os dados:

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_row']))
{
 $host="localhost";
 $username="root";
 $password="";
 $databasename="sample";
 $connect=mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
 $db=mysql_select_db($databasename);  
 
 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $age=$_POST['age'];
 $job=$_POST['job'];
 for($i=0;$i<count($name);$i++)
 {
  if($name[$i]!="" && $age[$i]!="" && $job[$i]!="")
  {
   mysql_query("insert into employee_table values('$name[$i]','$age[$i]','$job[$i]')");  
  }
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Muita obrigada Bins.

Comment: Poderia me ajudar ainda mais um pouco? Estou tentando fazer com os inputs sejam criados de acordo com o intervalo de dias. Eu consegui fazer isso com a tabela fixa, mas n consigo com a dinamica. O primeiro passo seria um for com a variavel que armazena a quantidade de dias, mas ele simpleste n aceita. Tem alguma sugestão?